# Google App Engine. JPA. @ManyToOne causes org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager$ChildWithoutParentException

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

```
@Entity
public class Group
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;
}


@Entity
public class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Group group;
}
```

After the following code :

```
EntityManager entityManager = EntityManagerFactoryHolder.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
Group group = new Group();
entityManager.persist(group);
User user = new User();
user.setGroup(group);
entityManager.persist(user);
entityManager.close();
```

I get the following error

> Detected attempt to establish User(28) as the parent of Group(27) but
>   the entity identified by Group(27) has already been persisted without
>   a parent.  A parent cannot be established or changed once an object
>   has been persisted.
>   org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager$ChildWithoutParentException:
>   Detected attempt to establish User(28) as the parent of Group(27) but
>   the entity identified by Group(27) has already been persisted without
>   a parent.  A parent cannot be established or changed once an object
>   has been persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that this only works with back association. Added @OneToMany set to Group object and it works now.