# Google App Engine. JPA. How to implement @ManyToOne without backward @OneToMany?

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

As I found when asking [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788110/google-app-engine-jpa-manytoone-causes-org-datanucleus-store-appengine-datast) to have @ManyToOne association work I need to add 
backward @OneToMany entity.

But after that I found that I cannot now find these entities specifying it's own id.
I need to specify also parent's id.

Here's how my id looks like:

```
User(1)/Issue(2)
```

So, I need to find in such way:

```
entityManager.find(Issue.class, KeyFactory.createKey(KeyFactory.createKey("User",1),"Issue",2))
```

And I wonder, what will be if I have several ManyToOne fields.
Please, follow me to the exact instructions on how to deal with @ManyToOne fields in GAE.

Comment: Yes, I have to use **User(1)/Issue(2)** as key, since entity key is not guaranteed to be unique (unless it is root entity), GAE actually uses **application ID + ancestor path + entity ID** as a unique key.
Have you tried putting multiple @ManyToOne in entity class? I don't really think it could happen, otherwise it means your entity class have multiple parents.

Comment: Does the relation have to be "owned" ? (if so, which is the owner?) because GAE supports owned and unowned. Unowned obviously requires none of that

Comment: @DataNucleus, I just read about this classification. Seems that I need **unowned**. So, can I just put \@Unowned \@ManyToOne on the field to make it **unowned** ? Is it supported in JPA-2 for GAE ?

Comment: @Unowned is a GAE concept (how the objects are interrelated in the datastore), available using their v2.x plugin. That means that the User and Issue are stored in different entity groups, but that the Key of the Issue is independent of the User; so comes down to your model and how you want to handle those classes as to whether it makes sense to do that